# the type or protocol named "CustomDelegate" does not exist

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm having a problem that is becoming a nightmare. Recently, I opened a project and mysteriously, the Xcode pointed out an error that did not happen before: "the type or protocol named StickerCollectionViewDelegate does not exist". I didn't make any changes to my code! It's a delegate I created and it was working before and now it does not.

```
@class StickerCollectionView;
@protocol StickerCollectionViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)addSticker:(Sticker*)sticker;

@end

@interface StickerCollectionView : UICollectionView <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<StickerCollectionViewDelegate> stickerDelegate;

@end
```

On my main view controller:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <StickerCollectionViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Try cleaning your build folder and restarting Xcode. Also, make sure you're not import looping (class A.h importing classB.h & classB.h importing classA.h)

Answer (score 2):

What file is throwing the error? Any file that makes reference to your `StickerCollectionViewDelegate` protocol will need to `#import` the header file that defines it.

If the error is coming from the file that defines the protocol then the problem is with Xcode, and it's time to try cleaning your project, quitting Xcode, and all that other lovely nonsense you have to do when Xcode loses it's mind.